# how do I pull multiple items out of a table with one join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a join, I would like it to collect the name of two items by joining the item table on the item id for two different item ids.  For example:

```
SELECT first_item_name, second_item_name FROM items JOIN order_table ON ...
```

and here is where I am stuck - what I effectively need to do is two joins on one table, the first to select the first item's name:

```
ON first_item_id = first_id
```

and then go back and select the second item's name with another join:

```
ON second_item_id = second_id
```

my question is can this be done from within a single join?

Thank you.

Comment: can you give structure of ;your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word; No.

The thing to bear in mind is that the

```
On value = value
```

clause must evaluate to TRUE for each tuple (think of a tuple as in effect record but a record created by the join) created by the join.  So if tableA.col1 = tableB.col1 is true for the first tuple than it cannot **at the same time** also be true for tableA.col1 = tableB.col1 for the second tuple .  And here is the wrinkle; in both cases tableA.col1 = tableB.col1 but only for each tuple individually, in a way you are asking can I have tuple1 and tuple2 at the same time.

And do not be concerned about joining more than once to the same table.  It is not wrong, not inherently going to cause bad performance or for any other reason to be avoided.

Comment: You could create a mysql function to do this, like GetItemName(ItemID). I disagree that it won't cause performance problems though. If you join to the same large table lots of times, performance will diminish.

Comment: "not inherently going to cause bad performance"  Any join, in fact any statement, has a risk of causing bad performance.  Joining a table to itself has no inherent risk.  An multiple joins, unindexed join, joining 2 large data sets, etc can often cause bad performance.  Not the specific fact that it is a multiple join to a given table.

Comment: Your statement is logically true, but the semantics are not helpful. "Can often cause" versus "not inherently" is a logical point, but while I enjoy those sorts of discussions it doesn't help the OP. On the other hand, SQL is an extremely pedantic language so maybe it does help for them to start thinking that way.